# Equivalent of getElementById in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm moving some of my html/javascript pages over to AngularJS. Previously, my script (an HTML5 audio player) rendered some HTML elements on the page and then ran some script to use those elements, thusly:

**audioplayer.html:**

```
...
<div id="timeline">

        <div id="showElapsed">

            <div class="bg">

            </div>

          </div>
        <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
...

<script> 
        var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead

        var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline

        // timeline width adjusted for playhead
        var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;
    ...
```

Now i'd like to move this into a controller / view layout in angular, so;

**index.html**

```
...
<div ng-controller="AudioPlayerController">
          <div ng-include="'views/audioPlayerView.html'"></div>
      </div>
...
```

**main.js**

```
...
function AudioPlayerController($scope) {

        var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead

        var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline
        // timeline width adjusted for playhead
        var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;
...
```

**audioPlayerView.html:**

```
...
<div id="timeline">

        <div id="showElapsed">

            <div class="bg">

            </div>

          </div>
        <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
...
```

Now I have a problem - `document.getElementById('timeline');` doesn't return anything because its moved to a controller. Furthermore, the controller is called BEFORE the view, so how can the controller reference an element FROM the view?

I realize this is basic Angular layout stuff, but I can't figure it out. Could someone help me think in a more angular way please!? Thanks.

Comment: If you're working with the DOM in Angular you should use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: This is not how you use angular, angular is built for single page apps which makes use of [routing](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) to load pages as and when needed.

Comment: the audio player is common to all routes, so was attempting to add it to the index page, but a ui-router solution would work for me too...

Comment: in angular1 directive,in link callback - you get `$element`, using $element, you get whatever elements you want in jquery style do the needed DOM manipulation, but do DOM manipulation only when its unavaoidable, mostly work with JS code to do show/hide/click stuff

Comment: So first step = take the code out of a the controller and into a directive, yes?

Comment: you can put your script in normal angular functions... only use $timeout... for example: $timeout(function() { angular.element('#myElement').focus(); }) could be inserted in a normal scoped function

Answer (score 2):

For dom interaction in angular you have directives elements
that implemented in the view.
directive link also complie after view is loaded, so no problem here.

note their declarations are written in **camel case** on the view, so:

javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('audioPlayer', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: 'path-to-your-page/audioPlayerView.html',
            link: function(element) {
               var playhead = element.find('playhead');

               // timeline width adjusted for playhead
               var timelineWidth = element.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;
            }
        };
    });
```

html:

```
 <div audio-player>
            <div id="showElapsed">

                <div class="bg">

                </div>

              </div>
            <div id="playhead"></div>   
 </div>
```

**note that**, 
in "angular way" you shouldn't make 
document.getElementById(), just ==> angular.element()